# Error in function prototype

Tags: c++

Why does this code result in error?

```
class CommonRuntine
{
    public:
        struct TProcess;
        TProcess GetProcessByName(LPCSTR ProcessName);
};
```

It says "**E2293 ) Expected**" on the "*};*" bit

PS : LPCSTR is a type

Comment: You should provide more context.  Maybe the error is not on this line, or maybe `LPCSTR` is a weird macro.

Comment: #include <windows.h> - Worked!!! , Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <windows.h>
```

Had to include the file defining that type

Comment: This is the reason I have not asked a question here. One finds the answer oneself first... (I wonder, can one accept their own answer ;))

Comment: You can accept yourself after a few days. Do you see a `delete` button under the question?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the error is elsewhere in the file - I would check the lines prior to this one for a missing closing parenthesis.